# High CPU usage at google meet

Tags: 22.04

Ubuntu 22.04
When I enter google meet my CPU usage spikes to 50% on average. What could be the reason?

My laptop (in case if you need):
Lenovo Thinkpad T460: core I5 6300, 8GB RAM 256 GB SSD

Comment: "high cpu usage"? I would call that normal (but i might be mistaken :-)) With just this is is going to difficult to tell, Do include a copy/paste of for instance top or htop of the 1st couple of lines. That might help.

Comment: that sounds like normal CPU usage, you are streaming video to and from your laptop.

Comment: Ok, thank you. thought that it's unusually high.

Comment: Google Meet does have a tendency to hog CPUs. They might be trying to tune your video with AI enhancements while eating up CPU. You can adjust send/receive resolutions to manage your CPU usage and see if the usage drops.